# How to create a single solution in VS with multiple git repository projects

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, github, repository

Ok,

I have looked far and wide and the information I have found about this - which isn't much is beyond me to decypher.

I have a Visual Studio Solution which I want to contain two different projects. Each project is a completely different repository on Git.

One project is a library that the main application in the other project uses (as does a few other projects which is why the library is separate).

How do I set it up in Visual Studio to do this? 
Really baby steps please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really makes no difference if projects are in same or different repositories. Just use VS for coding, and git client for version control. You may use or may not use submodules. For example, our project has the following structure, we are not using submodules (but we could):

- Shared (git repository, projects are here)
- Application (git repository, projects are here, solution is here)
- ThirdParty (git repository, external dependencies are here)

Answer (score 2):

### Visual Studio tools for Git does not support this setup.

The only way to make to do this is to make use of the git submodules options from the commandline and communicate to git using some other medium than Visual Studio Tools for Git.